# Attribute error while installing pip command for python 2.7 windows 10

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install pip using the command:

`$python get-pip.py`

However, get the following error. I tried the solutions suggested by other users about the attribute error but nothing worked.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 25, in <module>
    import shutil
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 12, in <module>
    import collections
  File "C:\Python27\lib\collections\__init__.py", line 55
    raise AttributeError(f'module {__name__!r} has no attribute {name!r}')
```

I have the right version of python installed and added to the PATH. When I type `python` on the console, I get the following output:

```
Python 2.7.16 (v2.7.16:413a49145e, Mar  4 2019, 01:37:19) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: Check `get-pip.py` You probably have the python3 version of that file.

Comment: I don't think python2 supports f-strings, so you have the python3 version

Answer (score 0):

Your Python 2.7 installation seems to be distorted: module `collections` contains code with `f''`-string which only works with Python 3.

My advice is to reinstall Python 2.7.